# Reading .xlsx file from a bytestring

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm trying to read an attached .xlsx file from an e-mail.

I have been able to retrieve an `email.message.Message` type which has a part of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. I should be able to read it using

```
file = part.get_payload(decode=True)
```

Which gives me a bytes object starting with

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x93\xe11\xb6\x93\x01\x00\x003\x07\x00\x00\x13\x00\
```

I would like to parse this into a dictionary using

```
io.BytesIO(gzip.decompress(file))
```

For some e-mails with a zipped .csv file this works but .xlsx files cannot open with this approach. I've looked online but I've not been able to find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Find a library that can read `xlsx` files. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing XML files, with separate files for styles, reusable strings etc. You'll have to understand how the Open XML format works if you want to read those XML files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Excel files come in compressed form and are automatically uncompressed when loaded into Excel itself.

The [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library is able to directly load these Excel files, for example:

```py
import openpyxl
import io

xlsx = io.BytesIO(part.get_payload(decode=True))
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    print(row)
```

If you need extra information per cell:

```py
for cells in ws.iter_rows():    
    print([cell.value for cell in cells])
```

Answer (score 3):

`.xlsx` is a ZIP rather than GZip archive. These are two completely different formats.

While you can use the `zipfile` module to get its contents, you're still going to need some specialized package for Excel files to make sense of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Martin answered it more completely so I accepted his answer.

Comment: I didn't want to give specific examples because there are about half a dozen libs (most with very incomplete support), and your question is just about what to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

```
import openpyxl
import io

# The bytes object (Something like b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00...)
file = part.get_payload(decode=True)

xlsx = io.BytesIO(file)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for cells in ws.iter_rows():    
    print([cell.value for cell in cells])
```